# Installing a complete package into Mathematica

Tags: installation, package, wolfram-mathematica

I downloaded a Mathematica package (it's called  "automaticUnits" - http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/). I can make the functions work, but I would like to install all the documentation and tutorials so I can look it up in the help menu in case I need to.

The install feature does not seem to work very well, for this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Download http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/ zip file.
2. Extract AutomaticUnits from the above folder to `Applications` under `$UserBaseDirectory`, e.g. `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\`,

   ```
   In[1]:= $UserBaseDirectory
   Out[1]= C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica
   ```

   So now it looks like this on my windows

   [image: Explorer with new package]
3. From Mathematica

   ```
   Needs["AutomaticUnits`"]
   ?AutomaticUnits`*
   ```

   This is the result

   [image: Output]

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll try that in a second, doing a reinstall since I was moving these files around inside the installation folder.

Does the links in the documentation work?